# Is there a Virtual PC software that allows you to run Windows 8.1 and connect to Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I am looking to test out Windows 8.1 preview in a Virtual PC software. I require to be able to run the Windows 8.1 software within a Virtual PC and to be able to access the Internet through connecting wirelessly to a Wi-Fi network through the Windows 8.1. Is there a free Virtual P software that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the host machine has working wifi I think either Vmware Player (free) or VirtualBox (free and open source) should work. You don't say what OS the host machine is running. I have run both of these virtualizers on a host laptop running Windows 8.1 with wifi; the client systems (not running Windows 8.1, but I don't see why it should be different) had wifi access without problems.

Comment: how ridiculous that I get downvoted for giving a good answer to a question when someone else doesn't like the question...

Comment: This place is getting too anal.

Comment: Your answer is appreciated, do not understand how you got downvoted but hope me ticking your answer gets you a vote